# When creating a new object with forEach, some prperties show up as $$typeof: Symbol(react.element) React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, foreach

So I am receiving an array of Objects, each one has a "attributes.seller" property. Then I am using a forEach( ) to go over each one and create a new object with only the properties I need and pushing them to a new array, including the Seller property.
The issue is that on ALL the received objects the "Seller" property exists and its a string.

However, after constructing the new object most of the seller properties show as "seller: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'button', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}"

BUT not all of them, some do show correctly. So IDK whatI am doing wrong if my code was working before and it still works but not for all the items.

[This is the object array i am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs3AP.png)

This is where I itirate over each object:

```
createdResults.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item.attributes.seller);
      const offer = {
        itemId: Number(item.attributes.itemId),
        token: item.attributes.token,
        amount: item.attributes.amount,
        price: item.attributes.price,
        seller: item.attributes.seller,
      };
      createdArr.push(offer);
```

Even  when I log out to the console items.attributes.itemId, it shows EVERY SINGLE property just fine.

The issue is after I have pushed each new object into the new array that the "seller" property of it shows like this:
[New Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJgxq.png)

```
 const getEvents = async () => {
    let createdArr = [];
    
    const created = new Moralis.Query("SaleCreateddd");
    

    const createdResults = await created.find();
    
    

    createdResults.map((item) => {
      // Until here, the seller string shows up correctly for each item
      console.log(item.attributes.seller);
      const offer = {
        itemId: Number(item.attributes.itemId),
        token: item.attributes.token,
        amount: item.attributes.amount,
        price: item.attributes.price,
        seller: item.attributes.seller,
      };
      // Its after the forEach loop that the seller property gets distorted

      createdArr.push(offer);
```

Comment: Show us the code where the `createdArr` is used. It looks like its used in the `render` and the seller field gets map to a react element.

Comment: Updated. I cant use the array withou the seller property. However the issue lies somewhere in that forEach loop. Before i loop over it, all the seller info is there. After the loop, most show up as $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)

Comment: @MandingoSan The problem is unlikely in the `forEach` loop. Rather, some other code is *modifying* the objects you created just fine, *after* the loop - [before you are inspecting the logged array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572). Please show us the complete code, especially the parts where you use React JSX syntax (`<button …>`)

Answer (score 0):

itemId is already an integer remove `Number()`

then you are forgetting `.seller`

````js
createdResults.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item.attributes.seller);
      const offer = {
        itemId: item.attributes.seller.Number(itemId),
        token: item.attributes.seller.token,
        amount: item.attributes.seller.amount,
        price: item.attributes.seller.price,
        seller: item.attributes.seller.seller,
      };
      createdArr.push(offer);```
````

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but it actually does come in as a string "14" then I convert it to a number